# Can 2 classes share one struct?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have 2 classes `Foo` and `Cook`, and `Book` is a struct.

Previously `Book` is a global variable and I would like to change it to be owned by `Foo` so that I can have many `Foo` with their own `Book`.

`Cook` reads `Book`, but `Foo` will be updating `Book`'s value from time to time.

The following code that I tested, doesn't work. I am very new in C++, I don't understand why this doesn't work.

```
class Foo {
private:
    Book book;
    Cook cook;
public:
    Foo();
    virtual ~Foo();
};

class Cook {
private:
    Book * book;
public:
    Cook();
    virtual ~Cook();
    void setBook(Book * book);
};
```

Then inside `Foo`'s constructor there is a: `cook.setBook(&book);`

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what, exactly?

Comment: It compiles, but gives wrong calculation. So I think the Book when accessed from Cook doesn't reflect updated value.

Comment: The way you're casually sharing a pointer to a private property of another object is really a bad idea, that's bound to lead to tons of trouble. What's better is constructing a singular `book` and passing it in to both of these where neither owns it, but the ownership is managed by something like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr9) if you cannot establish a strong ownership policy. Another approach is to have `Cook` as a friend class of `Foo` so it can get the data it needs without needing its own pointer.

Comment: Yeah I will be changing that, but I just wanted to understand what is happening.

Comment: I can't tell you what's happening as your example here is obviously missing the part of your code that has a problem. This looks like a bad design, it will fail unless used in a very specific way, but other than that it's *technically* valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing should work fine, although I can't agree enough with [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) that you should be using a `std::shared_ptr`.

If you're seeing your values get out of sync it's likely that you have overwritten `Foo.book` but that change has not been propagated to `Foo.cook.book`.

Possible better design would be:

```
class Foo {
private:
    Book book;
    Cook cook;
    Book& getBook();
public:
    Foo() : cook(std::bind(getBook,this));
    virtual ~Foo();
};

class Cook {
private:
    std::function<Book&()> _memfunptr;
public:
    Cook(std::function<Book()> memfunptr): _memfunptr(memfunptr);
    virtual ~Cook();
};
```

From here any time you wanted to reference `Foo.book` inside of `Foo.cook` you could just use the `Cook._memfunptr` to access it.

As a note here some of you're problems might be related to class implementation? You should have a semicolon at the end of each `class`'s scope, and you're `Cook` constructor should be defined `Cook();` *not* `Cook cook;`.